# MWAA Apache Airflow DAG error importing EcsOperator

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I am trying to deploy an Airfow DAG to MWAA.

My `requirements.txt`:

```
apache-airflow[amazon] == 3.2.0
```

I import `EcsOperator` like this:

```py
from airflow.contrib.operators.ecs_operator import EcsOperator
```

However, I get this error:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/mydag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/mydag.py", line 4, in <module>
    from airflow.contrib.operators.ecs_operator import EcsOperator
ImportError: cannot import name 'EcsOperator' from 'airflow.contrib.operators.ecs_operator' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/ecs_operator.py)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct `requirements.txt`:

*(empty)*

And the correct import:

```py
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs import ECSOperator
```

Note the casing!

Comment: `ECSOperator` (capital "ECS") is deprecated. Reference: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs/index.html#airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs.ECSOperator

Comment: It doesn't appear to work with `EcsOperator`: `from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs import EcsOperator
ImportError: cannot import name 'EcsOperator' from 'airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs.py)`

Comment: see my answer for explanation why it didn't work for you

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong here?

You might be referencing a different version (1.10.12?) of the Airflow documentation.

[airflow.contrib.operators.ecs_operator (1.10.12)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/ecs_operator/index.html)

The documentation for `3.2.0` is [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs/index.html). You can import the `EcsOperator` like this:

```py
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs import EcsOperator
```

[airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs (3.2.0)](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs/index.html#module-airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here so I'll compile a detailed answer since privious answers didn't cover all of them.

First, the updated import path (provider release 3.2.0) is:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.ecs import EcsOperator
```

The reason this doesn't work for you is because you install the provider with extras as:

```
apache-airflow[amazon]
```

as explained in the [provider extra docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/extra-packages-ref.html#providers-extras) when installing provider in that manner you get the provider version which was released at the time of the Airflow version that you are using. Thus you are not guaranteed to get the updated provider version. So in case you are using Airflow 2.2.4 (latest at the time of writing this answer) you will get Amazon provider version 3.0.0 which is not the most recent one.

To get updated provider you should install it as:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon
```

if you like to pick a specific version then:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon==3.2.0
```

Please note that you should always install from constraint files provided by Airflow. Example:

```
pip install "apache-airflow-providers-amazon" --constraint "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-main/constraints-3.7.txt"
```

Note that the provider is referring to constraints-main which constantly updated and not to `constraints-2.2.4` or any other specific Airflow version.
You can read more about it in the doc about [Installation and upgrading of Airflow providers separately](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#installation-and-upgrading-of-airflow-providers-separately).

Comment: With MWAA I don’t run pip, instead AWS does something with the provided requirements.txt

Comment: If you want updated provider version specify the package directly as `apache-airflow-providers-amazon` - I suggest you will contact MWAA support for assistance. I wrote what should be done when using Airflow - this should be possible with MWAA - if not then they need to provide you some alternative as using extras you can not get the latest provider version.